# Fast implementation to output nested dict to JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Each line of the JSON has a structure looks as the following

```
|- Sentence
|   |-- WordPosition:
|   |--   |-- Candidate
|   |--   |--   |-- index:
|   |--   |--   |-- retrievals
```

Example of a line in JSON output (parameter `num_retrieval`=2)
[image]

Current implementation

```
def output_conll_retrievals_to_json(output_file, conll_mcs,conll_sentences, num_retrieval):

    num_sentence = len(conll_sentences)

    with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(num_sentence):
            num_position = len(conll_sentences[i])
            level2 = dict()
            level1 = dict()
            for j in range(num_position):
                level0 = dict()
                for mc in conll_mcs[i][j]:
                    mc_str = ' '.join(mc.mention_string)
                    level0[mc_str] = dict()
                    level0[mc_str]['index'] = mc.mention
                    level0[mc_str]['retrievals'] = self.get_one_mc_retrievals(mc, num_retrieval)
                level1[conll_sentences[i][j]] = level0
            level2[' '.join(conll_sentences[i])] = level1
            json.dump(level2, f)
            f.write('\n')
```

Note that `self.get_one_mc_retrievals` is implemented in parallel, accessing a memory map and performs a hierarchical search. Executing the snippet of code, status showing that CPUs are under-used (like 10-20% for each core as writing is serial programming) and the whole JSON output takes 8 days (approximately 3000 sentences with `num_retrievals` of 100) to generate. Would it be possible to boost the speed (i.e., Cython, parallel or something else)?

** Edited **

This just comes off my head, would it be possible to utilize *multiprocessing* to speed up JSON writing? Right now, my code is kind of serially doing a process that retrieves a dict from reading `conll_mcs[i]` and writes a line to the JSON file. If I could simultaneously perform many of such a process, speed will very likely improve, however I am still trying to find how to put such an idea into practice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the relationship between `conll_mcs` and `conll_sentences`?

Comment: You are asking questions about code that you are not showing us, or referencing. There are certainly performance-enhancing options available to you. But you need to tell us (in detail) what you are doing, how you are doing it, and what constraints you are under. If `get_one_mc_retrievals` is slow, then show us that code.

Comment: I found this link pretty helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file [multiprocessing safely writing to a file].